# Where should we advertise our site in 2019?

Tags: discussion, site-promotion

Last year we [collected ideas for ads to run on other SE sites](https://writing.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1464/1993).  This year I have a two-fold question: where on SE should we advertise (and how), and are there places *outside* of SE where we should be spreading the word about our site (and if so, how)?

I'll start a community-wiki answer to track stuff we've already done, but please use other answers to talk about how we can promote our site, particularly aiming at promotions that will draw more (quality) questions.

Answer (score 11):

## Roleplaying DMs love writing

[RPG.SE](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/) would be a good place to advertise this site. That's where I came from and I imagine other RPGers are also into writing. There is a lot of crossover with story arcs and plots.

I'm not an artist to create a good ad, but it could read:

> Sick of players ruining your plot? Try writing instead... Writing.se

Thanks to Paulster2 this ad is now available [here](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8782/48759)

Comment: I like the text -- thanks!

Comment: I like the text as well. I am working on the image for RPG and SciFi. I'll see what I can get done in the next couple of days.

Comment: Please see the new ad posted for RPG in the wiki above! :o)

Answer (score 7):

Community-promotion ads we have submitted on other SE sites:

- [Worldbuilding](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7067/28)
- [Software Engineering](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8856/124448) (targeting technical writing)
- [Code Review](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9073/33153) (ditto)
- [TeX - LaTeX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8080/169608) (ditto)
- [Science Fiction & Fantasy](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/12308/21234)
- [RPG.SE](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8782/51904)

Comment: Also, if you *really* would like these to benefit Writing.SE, upvote these on the sites where posted to ensure they are seen. We need six upvotes per ad in order for it to become live.Thanks!